# C# - Complex variable-assignment

Tags: c#, class, list, interface

i have a class `Row`.
This class should have a Content-property. Currently the content is of type: `List<IRowContent>`

(`IRowContent` is a interface)

Other classes `Column` and `TextContent`, `ImageContent` implements the interface `IRowContent`.

I can add now some Columns to the list or real "content" (Text or a image).

But you can also add columns and text/image. But if a row contains text/image it should not contain another item.

How can i design my class-structure to support this?

**Edit**: some additionals infos:
I want to build a layout with "**fluent interfaces**" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

And my idee is to prevent wrong use by intellisense of VisualStudio.

Here my classes:
The Layout have a column-list.

```
class Layout
   {
      //Attributes
      public Color Background { get; set; }
      public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
      public uint Margin { get; set; }

      public Layout AddColumn(Column c)
      {
         return null;
      }

      public Layout SetColumnList(List<Column> c)
      {
         return null;
      }
   }
```

The column has a list of content (IColumnContent). The column itself is from IRowContent.

```
class Column : IRowContent
   {
      public List<IColumnContent> Content { get; private set; }

      public Column AddToContent(IColumnContent obj)
      {
         return null;
      }

      public Column SetContent(List<IColumnContent> objs)
      {
         return null;
      }
   }
```

Same for Row with IRowContent:

```
   class Row : IColumnContent
   {
      public List<IRowContent> Content { get; private set; }

      //...
   }
```

ImageContent and TextContent implements both interfaces:

```
class TextContent : IRowContent, IColumnContent

class ImageContent : IRowContent, IColumnContent
```

Comment: Are you aware of the .net interface naming conventions?

Comment: Ew, an interface not prefixed with `I`--that could be troublesome. And I'd probably answer this, but it looks like Jon Skeet's already on deck and will have a [better] solution by the time I type this comment.

Comment: @Brad: Nope, wasn't planning on getting involved in this one, so go ahead and answer :)

Comment: Sorry you'r right :-) I fixed the interface-name

Comment: @JonSkeet: *shock and dismay* I don't believe it...

Comment: @user437899: typically interface names start with a capital 'I', i.e. `IRowContent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the interface

```
interface IRowContent 
{
    bool SupportsOtherChildren{ get; }
    ...
}

class ImageContent : IRowContent
{
    public bool SupportsOtherChildren
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}

class Column : IRowContent
{
    public bool SupportsOtherChildren
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

You can override a collection's insert and remove methods to support this behavior:

```
 class RowContentCollection : Collection<IRowContent>
    {
        bool containsSingleItem = false;
        protected override void InsertItem(int index, IRowContent item)
        {
            if (containsSingleItem)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Collection contains an item that doesnt allow other items.");

            containsSingleItem = !item.SupportsOtherChildren;

            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            if (!this[index].SupportsOtherChildren)
                containsSingleItem = false;

            base.RemoveItem(index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also agree with this, a collection with built-in limitations supersedes a generic `List<T>`, and I also agree the interface needs more to support the "must stand along" flag.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize and to make sure I understand you correctly:

The `Row` class should contain a list of columns. Every column can be an object of type `Column`, `TextContent` or `ImageContent`. All three of these classes implement the `RowContent` interface (which in my opinion should be named `IColumnContent`...).

If that is correct, the restriction you're trying to impose (which I don't fully understand, to be honest) is not a matter of class design, but a matter of add/remove logic. I'd declare the `Content` property as

```
private List<RowContent> m_internalColumns;

public RowContent[] Columns { get { return m_internalColumns.ToArray(); }}
```

and create `Add` and `Remove` methods like the following (pseudo-code):

```
public void Add(RowContent column)
{
    if (adding column of type <typeof(column)> is allowed)
        m_internalColumns.Add(column);
}

public void Remove(RowContent column)
{
    m_internalColumns.Remove(column);
}
```

Comment: Agreed, sticking with a generic `List<T>` isn't going to impose the limitations necessary. Time to make a custom list that implements its own Add/Remove functionality.

Comment: What does the m in m_internalColumns stand for?

Comment: @bas: `m_...` is a way to declare private Members (naming convention, `m` meaning `member`).

Comment: "member" - it kind of survived my C++ days when it was used to distinguish member variables from local variables. May not be consistent with .NET naming conventions, but I can't stop my fingers from typing it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `Row` class generic:

```
class Row<T : IRowContent> {
    public List<T> Content { ... }
}
```

Then you can have a `Row<Column>`, which can only contain columns, or a `Row<TextContent>`, which can contain only text content. You can even have a `Row<IRowContent>` which allows for mixed content.

If you want a row that can only contain text *and* image content (but no columns), add an interfance `IRealContent : IRowContent` and have `TextContent`  and `ImageContent` implement `IRealContent`. Then, a `Row<IRealContent>` can only contain text and images.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract the details about the problem to the interface itself.

```
public interface IRowContent
{
      bool SupportsChildren { get; }

      // other properties
}
```

I would also introduce custom Add and Remove methods to the Row class that determine if the content being added can support additional content.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do one of 2 things. Either:

Instead of using `Row.Content.Add()` to add items, add a method to `Row` for adding content. `Row.AddContent(iRowContent content);` and put your 'logic' in that method for determining if whatever item can be added or not.

Or, instead of using a List, implement your own collection that inplements `IList` and write the `Add()` method in a way that contains your logic.